# Помогите я не могу понять почему это не работает

Tags: python

```
a = 0
text = input("Введите текст: ")

for i in text:
    if i == "a" or "б":
        a += 1
print(a)
```

Почему так это работает,

```
a = 0
text = input("Введите текст: ")

for i in text:
    if i == "a":
        a += 1
print(a)
```

А так нет?

Comment: Я пытался написать программу подсчета знаков в тексте решил написать через цикл ``` for ``` и оно работает в первом варианте, но не работает во втором я не могу понят почему

Comment: Какого подсчёта каких знаков? Приведите примеры входных и ожидаемых выходных данных, а то из вашего кода и ваших комментариев логика совершенно непонятна

Comment: if i == "a" or i=="б" или if i in ["a","б"]